# How to prove $\int_e f_k(x)dx=0$ for $k=1,2,\cdots,n$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_k\in L(E),(k=1,2,\cdots,n)$. If $0<m(E)<+\infty, \  \  \int_E f_k(x)dx=0, k=1,2,\cdots,n.$

Then how to prove for any $\lambda:0<\lambda<1$, there is a subset $e: m(e)=\lambda m(E)$ such that  $\int_e f_k(x)dx=0$ for $k=1,2,\cdots,n$

I have no idea at all.

First, for each $f_k$, can we find a $e_k$ s.t $ m(e_k)=\lambda m(E)$ and $\int_{e_k} f_k(x)dx=0$

Second, does $f_k$ shares a common subset satisfying the above condition?

Comment: i am unfamiliar with some of the notations you use. what is $L(E)$?

Comment: $L(E)$ means Lebesgue integrable on set $E$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of [Lyapunov's convexity theorem](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1990-108-01/S0002-9939-1990-0993737-0/). The theorem has some pretty short  proofs (see the linked paper and its list of references). Perhaps a direct proof of this result could be a bit shorter, but not much shorter.

To apply Lyapunov's convexity theorem, introduce vector-valued measure
$$\nu(e) = \left( \int_e f_1,\dots, \int_e f_n , \frac{m (e)}{ m(E)} \right)\in \mathbb R^{n+1}$$
By assumption, the range of this measure contains the points $(0,\dots,0,0)$ (take $e=\varnothing$)   and $(0,\dots,0,1)$ (take $e=E$). By convexity, it also contains $(0,\dots,0,\lambda)$.

Comment: i tried to do this myself and found this quite hard.